# Is there a way to view chat bot !commands used in a Twitch chat without typing in the chat?

Tags: twitch

As I understand, on Twitch, some stream titles have words coupled with exclamation points, which are commands you can type in chat to get some info from a bot.

For example, highlighted in yellow:

[image]

Is there a way to try these commands without everyone else seeing that you are typing them in the chat?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's [not connected to a game](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14634/185203)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what bot they may be using to interpret the commands, you may have different options.

The channel "Mixwell" in your example image seems to use Nightbot.  Knowing this, you can plug their channel name into this URL:

`https://nightbot.tv/t/<channelName>/commands`

Where `<channelName>` you replace with the name of the channel.  Mixwell's commands can be viewed [here](https://nightbot.tv/t/mixwell/commands).

Another bot I've seen used in channels is Fossabot.  It's a similar situation - use this URL:

`https://fossabot.com/commands/<channelName>`

For example, Summit1g uses this bot.  His commands can be found [here](https://fossabot.com/commands/summit1g).  I actually found this by Google searching the term "fossabot summit1g" and it was the first link.  So when all else fails, Google may have what you are looking for!

Comment: Sidenote - a lot of channels will have a `!commands` command, that will usually point you to one of these URLs.

Comment: For completeness, also adding the URL for Moobot: `https://moo.bot/r/commands#<channelName>`